# How do ring theorists think about square roots?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ denote a commutative ring.

Then it seems to me that we can adjoin to $R$ a square-root of $4$ as follows:

$$R[\sqrt{4}] = R[x]/(x^2-4)$$

This defines a functor $\mathbf{CRing} \rightarrow \mathbf{CRing}$ given on objects by $R \mapsto R[\sqrt{4}]$. In some sense, we might say that the square-root of $4$ "is" this functor.

But this functor has some very weird effects. In particular, the element $\sqrt{4}$ will almost never equal $2$ in $R[\sqrt{4}]$, despite that $(\sqrt{4})^2$ equals $4$. And $R[\sqrt{4}]$ usually won't be an integral domain.

I'm not quite sure what to make of this.

> **Questions.**
>
> - Is the meaning of the notation $R[\sqrt{4}]$ considered unambiguous?
> - If so, does it mean $R[x]/(x^2-4)$, or does it mean something else?
> - More generally, how do ring theorists think about square roots?

Comment: $R[x]/(x^2-4)$ is never an integral domain. If $\alpha$ is the residue class of $x$, then $\alpha \neq 2$ and $\alpha \neq -2$, but $(\alpha-2)(\alpha+2) = 0$. (Assuming that $R$ has a multiplicative identity $1$, and $2 = 1+1$, $4 = 1+1+1+1$.)

Comment: The second bullet point is probably what you would see, and the first bullet point will be a likely abbreviation. As far as I know, the only way to think about square roots is as solutions to $x^2-a=0$. What symbol you label a particular solute seems rather arbitrary.